# How to get a member value from derived class?

Tags: c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following base class:

```
class person{
public:
  person();
  string name;
  int age;
};
```

I have the following derived class:

```
class student : public person
{
   student();
   int grade;
};
```

In the implementation of the `student` constructor I get the name from some config file.

How can I assign the name from the derived class to the `person` class (to be the default value).

I'm aware that this implementation might be wrong, but that's what I need right now.

Comment: `this.name = something;` doesn't work?

Comment: `student stud; stud.name = name_from_file;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class person{
private:
  string name;
  int age;
public:
  person();
protected:
  void setName(const &string);
  void setAge(const int);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only **ONE** `name` in your class hierarchy: in your base `person` class.

When you are assigning some value to the `name` in your derived class `student` - you are referring to that same field.